# Executing multi query using MySQL .Net Core ADO

Tags: c#, mysql, orm, ado.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a MySQL database library for a new new asp.net core site. I used a similar pattern back in the MVC5 days, using Datatable and DataSet. Those horrid data structures have been removed from Core and I wondered what would be the best method of carrying out a query with multiple result sets.

For example,

```
  public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<IDataRecord>> ExecuteMultiQuery(MySqlConnection connection, CommandType commandType, string commandText, params MySqlParameter[] commandParameters) {

        var returnObject = new List<List<IDataRecord>>();

        using (MySqlCommand command = PrepareCommand(connection, commandType, commandText, commandParameters)) {
            try {
                connection.Open();

                command.Prepare();

                MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

                do {

                    List<IDataRecord> resultSet = new List<IDataRecord>();

                    while (reader.Read()) {
                        resultSet.Add(reader);
                    }

                    returnObject.Add(resultSet);

                } while (reader.NextResult());

            }
            finally {
                connection.Close();
            }

            command.Parameters.Clear();

        }

        return returnObject;
    }
```

However, whilst stepping through the code I notice that the collections never actually hold any data. I have tested my stored procedure and this correctly returns the rows needed. Also, I have a bespoke micro-ORM akin to Dapper which takes care of the POCO binding. I'm happy with it and don't wish to rely on external nuget packages.

I just cannot make sense of why the method does not fill the collections...

Any guidance would be most appreciated.

P.S The `PrepareCommand` method call is private and simply returns a correctly populated MySqlCommand with the params.

P.P.S Don't mention EF to me as this is an awful framework with tedious binding times. I can bind models in a similar ExecuteReader method in around 75-90ms (not Dapper fast but quick enough) so I know the DBUtiltiy I have created works in other scenarios - just not with multi queries.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's been a while and only tumble weed here. But I can only suggest waiting for the new version of Core which will include the old DataSet, DataTable library as well as Transactions!.

As a workaround I return a IEnumerable and used reflection to populate the POCOs. Dirty but it will do as a compromise until Core is a fully formed framework.